# Override fetch method in JS and forward Promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch, isomorphic-fetch-api

I want to override the `fetch()` method of [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) such that, just before sending this request it calls `showLoader()` and after the request is finished, it calls `hideLoader()`. Now I want to override it such that the new fetch can be chained just like the original fetch method. So it should respect/forward all the Promises. In summary, I want to:

- Override original `fetch()` into `fetchPlus(extraArg)`
- `fetchPlus()` needs to do addtional work just before calling `fetch()` and just after `fetch()` completes.
- `fetchPlus()` should be a drop in replacement for usages of original `fetch()`
- It should support chaining so that I can do:

`fetchPlus(extraArg, originalArgs...).then(response => {...}).catch(error => {...});`

I'm fairly new to JS, React and Redux so please excuse me if I missed something obvious. I did read up on `fetch()` and know that it returns [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so that the response can be passed on further or errors be handled. I sort of figured out an ugly way of doing it where, I pass on the responseHandler and errorHandler functions as args to fetchPlus.

```
fetchPlus(extraArg, url, options, responseHandler, errorHandler) {
    showLoader(extraArg);
    fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => {
        hideLoader(extraArg);
        responseHandler(response);
    }.catch(error => { errorHandler(error); });
}
```

But I don't find it clean. I want to see if I can find a drop-in replacement for the original fetch where Promises are correctly passed along.

I would highly appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you want to *override* the `fetch` function, or just to create a new function, which would be a modified version of the `fetch` function?

Comment: I want to wrap the fetch function so that it does additional things before and after calling the real fetch(). So I guess you can call it overriding fetch() or modified version of fetch()? The answer below solves my problem.

Comment: Well, overriding would mean that you assign some other function to `fetch`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know that it returns a Promise, then why not just return?

```
fetchPlus(extraArg, url, options) {
    showLoader(extraArg);
    return fetch(url, options)
      .then(response => {
        hideLoader(extraArg);
        return response;
      })
}
```

Then use it:

```
fetchPlus(extraArg, url, options)
  .then(response => ...)
  .catch(error => ...)
```

Comment: Perfect! This works as I expected. Didn't realise I could return the Promise from the then handler thing. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yup that's what makes promises chainable.